# Cassandra 2.1 - Inter-DC Latency?

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax

We're using Cassandra 2.1 with three datacenters (different worldwide locations) and "NetworkTopologyStrategy" replication factor 3 for all keyspaces.

Performance is very poor when running a simple test using Datastax C# driver from a web server to the cluster (initializing an ISession takes 6-10 SECONDS).

It seems like the nodes are going across datacenters on every call, but we have been unable to determine the reason.

Performance is fast when logging into an individual node, and running a test query using cqlsh (<1ms query times).

Any suggestions?

Comment: what consistency level are you using?

Comment: @Schildmeijer We tried both "Two" and "Local Quorum" with the same result. It's the initial creation of a session via Datastax C# driver that takes a long time.

Comment: I don't know the details of the C# driver. Is it possible to tune connect concurrency? Connect against a local singe node cluster is fast I presume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Ensure you use LOCAL_ consistency levels. CL=TWO is not guaranteed to restrict the query to the local datacenter.

2) Ensure your driver is using a datacenter aware load balancing policy

3) In some cases, speculative retry can cause connection cross-DC in the event of a timeout - if you have a local node that is unusually busy and speculative retry enabled, consider that a potential problem.